# add class on targeted div on window scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I want to add class to list items that is fixed to web page outside the all parallax section, here is my code but its not working please help me to correct this . So When a user scrolls the page the class should added on that specific item having common id.

**NOTE:-** I don't want to affect plugin functionality i only want to add classes to fixed list items belongs to there Id

```
jQuery(window).on('scroll', function(e) {

    if ( $('body').scrollTop() > $('.section2').position.top ) {
        $('.scroll_item').addClass('scroll_item_active');

    }

}).trigger('scroll');
```

Comment: Please share some HTML too : )

Comment: Here is the url i want to affect section2 dots at the last of web page fixed

https://mobulous.in/mobulous/

Comment: jQuery's `position` is a function (or method, if you prefer) - you have to call it to return an object with `top` and `left` properties: `$('.section2').position().top`

Answer (score 0):

Just use position()

```
jQuery(window).on('scroll', function(e) {

    if ( $('body').scrollTop() > $('.section2').position().top ) {
        $('.scroll_item').addClass('scroll_item_active');

    }

}).trigger('scroll');
```